# c++, boost::random: генерация случайных данных с равномерным распределёнием

Tags: c++, случайные-числа, boost, генерация-случайных-данных

Приветствует, стоит задача на некотором действительном отрезке (условно от 0.0 до limit) случайно сгенерировать N точек, при этом точки должны быть распределены равномерно.

Сначала написал свой код, с использованием `rand()`, то поскольку точек много (около 100 миллионов), а `rand()` ограничен пределом в 2^16 значений и генерировать действительные числа проблематично, решил воспользоваться разработками умных людей и использовать `boost::random`.

В результате получился следующий код (активно использовал примеры):

```
#include <ctime>

#include <boost/random/linear_congruential.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_real.hpp>
#include <boost/random/variate_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/generator_iterator.hpp>

    typedef boost::minstd_rand base_generator_type;

    base_generator_type generator((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    boost::uniform_real<> uni_dist(0.0, myDataLimit);
    boost::variate_generator<base_generator_type&, boost::uniform_real<> > uni(generator, uni_dist);

    for (int index = 0; index < myDataSize; index++)
    {
        myData[index] = uni();
    }
```

У меня вопросы

1) всё ли корректно сделано?
Проверил данные - вроде как равномерно распределены, но всё таки.

2) уж очень брутальный код, возможно ли как-то более красиво это сделать, что-то типа

```
boost::mysuper_linear_random(myData, myData + myDataSize, 0, limit);
```

Comment: А можно Кнута томики открыть, там большой кусок по генерации случайных чисел. Может даже будет быстрее и оптимальнее. А можно пойти на random.org и накачать себе готовых файлов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще поизучал вопрос - C++11 решает кучу проблем

```
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

//    std::mt19937 gen((unsigned int)time(0));
std::random_device genSource;

std::uniform_real_distribution<> generator(0.0, myDataLimit);

for (int index = 0; index < myDataSize; index++)
{
    myData[index] = generator(genSource);
}

std::sort(myData, myData + myDataSize);
```

тот же boost, только встроенный и не такие навороченные конструкции писать надо